# Get MAC address for wirless network to connect using WlanApi and C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, wireless

How can I get the MAC address of a wireless network, but its profile is not saved on the computer using C# and then connect to this network using the WLanApi class?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) 
{ 
     string MACAddress = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();        
}
```