# Connect to WPA/WPA2 wireless network with password in Windows Phone 8/8.1 SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have read the [Connect to a wireless network in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318575/connect-to-a-wireless-network-in-c-sharp) question, and I want to do the same thing on Window Phone 8.1 SDK. Could I connect to WPA2 wireless network with password by using wireless profile on Window Phone? And Which methods correspond to wlanIface.SetProfile and wlanIface.Connect

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Windows Phone generally does not let applications change system settings. The best you can do is open the WiFi Settings page. See [Turn Windows Phone Settings On/Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145135/turn-windows-phone-settings-on-off)